# Same Css, Same browser, Same site, tested on different computer

Tags: html, css

[Homepage](http://www.troop77swf.com) Eagle page: /eagles.html CSS: [CSS/styles.css](http://www.troop77swf.com/CSS/styles.css)
I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious, but I can't seem to find it.

Both of these pages stem from the same CSS file for formatting. Why does the eagles page navigation bar appear so thick compared to the homepage?

Comment: Thank you ZackL points taken and I will bookmark and reference the help page.

Comment: @James Donnelly, zero323, cimmanon, Chris and JoshC: It has been pointed out repeatedly that I posted poorly. It was my first post and I used the format of a similar question changing only the link and the actual question. I will NOT do that again. Apologies, again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution, on your eagels.html you have the following structure for your top navigation

```
<ul>
    <h2>
        <li>..</li>
    </h2>
</ul>
```

The h2 is wrong there and it causes the navigation bar to be bigger, just get rid of it and it should work.

And the next time you ask a question here, please don't just copy/paste links to your website but show us the actual code **here with your question**.

[Asking Rules Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: I apologize for the link instead of the code, I used the format from a previous post that was related to mine but didn't answer my question. I will do as you suggested from here on. THANK YOU for the help, I GREATLY appreciate it.